# Unable to dismiss presenter controller after segue to another view

Tags: swift, segue

I have a landing page which needs to segue to a Login Page. Once the login page is open, the landing page should not be visible.

The problem I am facing is that I can present the new view, but I can still go back to the landing page.

This is my code :

```
@objc func segueToLogin(sender: UIButton) {
        if let vc = self.findViewController() {
            vc.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
                vc.present(LoginPage(), animated: true, completion: nil)
            })
        }
    }
```

Can someone clarify if this is the right way to go about this?

Comment: _but I can still go back to the landing page_ Do you have back arrow which can return you to your landing page or you can left swipe back?

Comment: No. The login page is displayed modally, overlapping the landing page as it were an alert. And I can swipe out the login page and go back to the Landing Page.